# Linux SSSD with two AD Domains

Tags: linux, centos, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I Joined my Centos Box to a Windows Active Directory Domain with

```
realm join --user=DomUser dom2.local
```

Without any Problems. The Domain hast a one-way Trust relationship to Dom1.
Our Windows Users can:

- Log-In with Dom1/User to Dom1/Host
- Log-In with Dom1/User to Dom2/Host
- Log-In with Dom2/User to Dom2/Host

On our Linux Boxes (in Dom2), only Dom2/Users can Log in. I found some evidence online, that sssd can be configured with two Domains, so i added a Block in the sssd config:

```
# cat /etc/sssd/sssd.conf 
[sssd]
domains = dom1.local, dom2.local
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/dom1.local]
ad_domain = dom1.local
krb5_realm = DOM1.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
enumerate = True


[domain/dom2.local]
ad_domain = dom2.local
krb5_realm = DOM2.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
#cache_credentials = True
cache_credentials = False
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
enumerate = True
```

Now if i try to log in with a Dom2 User i get the following:

```
pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=host.dom1.local user=user@dom2.local
pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user user@dom2.local: 6 (Permission denied)
Failed password for user@dom2.local from 10.10.0.10 port 34442 ssh2
```

Has someone succefully configured two AD Domains with sssd? Or any Idea how to do that?

Edit1:

With getent passwd i can see all users from both domains, and both:

```
id user1@dom1.local
id user2@dom2.local
```

work as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this an old thread but I think it will be useful for some of us.

If you want to use sssd with more than one domain, you have to do this :

From https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4035171 :

After the realm join command, add a second domain from a different forest to the [domain_realm] section of /etc/krb5.conf :

```
.dom1.local = DOM1.LOCAL
dom1.local = DOM1.LOCAL
```

And then join the domain dom1.local :

```
adcli join --host-keytab=/etc/krb5.keytab.dom1.local dom1.local
```

Change sssd.conf as follows :

```
[sssd]
domains = dom2.local,dom1.local
...
[domain/testing.com]
ad_domain = dom1.local
krb5_realm = DOM1.LOCAL
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
timeout = 3600
krb5_keytab = /etc/krb5.keytab.dom1.local
ldap_krb5_keytab = /etc/krb5.keytab.dom1.local
```

and restart sssd : `systemctl restart sssd`

Answer (score 0):

You really need to enable sssd logs and look there, see https://docs.pagure.org/SSSD.sssd/users/troubleshooting.html

Typically, PAM returns error 6 during auth when sssd switches to offline mode due to one of the servers being unreachable