# Linux, Basic password authentication against 2 different AD without joining domain

Tags: linux, active-directory, kerberos

We have AIX and Linux servers running with basic password authentication against a Windows AD using Kerberos, so it are local users with a username identical to their sAMAccountName in the AD and all that is done is the password check.

Both OS's use a simple krb5.conf

```
    [libdefaults]
        default_realm = COMPANYA.COM

    [realms]
            COMPANYA.COM {
                    kdc = ad.companya.com:88
                    admin_server = ad.companya.com:749
            }
    
    [domain_realm]
            .companya.com = COMPANYA.COM
            companya.com = COMPANYA.COM
```

This works fine on both OS's.

We now have the situation that there will be a company B and thus also a 2nd AD.
A user will never be available on both AD's, just on either one.

So I first started on AIX as I figured this would be the hardest to get working.

Updated the krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = COMPANYA.COM

[realms]
        COMPANYA.COM {
                kdc = ad.companya.com:88
                admin_server = ad.companya.com:749
        }
        COMPANYB.COM {
                kdc = ad.companyb.com:88
                admin_server = ad.companyb.com:749
        }

[domain_realm]
        .companya.com = COMPANYA.COM
        companya.com = COMPANYA.COM
        .companyb.com = COMPANYB.COM
        companyb.com = COMPANYB.COM
```

After a bit of research it seemed all I had to do was

```
chuser auth_domain=COMPANYB.COM <user>
```

this updates the /etc/security/user file and will do the password validation against de Company B AD.  So I was pleasantly surprised at how easy that was.

Next came Linux (Ubuntu boxes).
Did the same krb5.conf but sadly I can not find the equivalent command for chuser under Ubuntu to point that specific user to the other AD.

What I can find is pages about using sssd and joining the realm ([Linux SSSD with two AD Domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/875568/linux-sssd-with-two-ad-domains) and/or https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ad) but this is all more then needed (joining the realms).

what I figured out so far using tcpdump and kinit is the following:

```
kinit testuser@companyb.com 
<password>
kinit: KDC reply did not match expectations while getting initial credentials

kinit testuser@COMPANYB.COM
<password>
<no error>

login testuser@companyb.com
<password>
access denied

login testuser@COMPANYB.COM
<password>
access denied
```

Since kinit with full caps worked I had suspected the login would to, sadly it did not.

*update: login testuser@COMPANYB.COM works if the user is created on the Linux box as testuser@COMPANYB.COM, still not to happy with that*

(forgetting the fact its not realistic to asked users to do their domain in full caps)

So long story short, how to point specific users to another AD than the default one in the krb5.conf file.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I gotten a bit further the last week and this seems to work.
Although I am still looking into the exact details on how PAM works.

updated/changed the /etc/pam.d/common-auth

original

```
auth   [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth   [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
```

new version

```
auth    sufficient           pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 realm=COMPANYA.COM
auth    sufficient           pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000 realm=COMPANYB.COM
auth    sufficient           pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
```

when logging in as a company A user it checks the AD of company A and since the user exists there the password is verified.
when logging in as a company B user it checks the AD of company A, the user does not exists there and it then goes to check company B and since the user exists there the password is verified.

it's not as nice as AIX does it but it works none the less.

Regards,